# How to connect to an Oracle 10g database on the host computer from Ubuntu installed in VMware?

Tags: virtual-machines, oracle10g

I have Oracle 10g installed in my host system which is running on Windows 7. I have also installed Ubuntu in the same system using VMware. Now I have written some program in Ubuntu which needs to connect the Oracle database installed in my host system. Programmatic the code is correct but the connection is not happening. I am sure of this because I can't open Oracle in Ubuntu using the default address 127.0.0.1:8080 So how to connect the database to the virtual OS?

Answer (score 1):

Address `127.0.0.1` means *this computer*, so if you use it in a virtual machine, then it points to the virtual machine and not the host system.

To connect to the host, you need to use host's IP address. Your virtual machine should be able to access host's IP address, but if it can't, check virtual machine's network configuration in VMware. Also make sure that Oracle is listening on host's IP address and not just `127.0.0.1`.